# How do you initialize a vector bool matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I come from a mostly Java background (I use Java for algorithm challenges) , but I'm trying to practice my C++. This is my solution to a problem in which I need a vector bool matrix.

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        
        string result = "";
        
        vector<vector<bool>> dp(s.length());
        
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                
                dp[i][j] = s[i] == s[j] && (j - i < 3 || dp[i + 1][j - 1]);
                
                if (dp[i][j] && (result.empty() || j - i + 1 > result.length())) {
                    
                    result = s.substr(i, j + 1);
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
};
```

This solution works in Java actually. In Java, I just do:

```
boolean[][] = new boolean[s.length()][s.length()];
```

As you see, I want to create a bool matrix in which the rows and columns are all of size s.length(). Unfortunately in my C++ solution, the compiler gives me this error:

```
Line 86: Char 2: runtime error: store to null pointer of type 'std::_Bit_type' (aka 'unsigned long') (stl_bvector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_bvector.h:95:2
```

I am certain the problem is how I am initializing the vector bool matrix. What can I do to solve this issue ? How do I initialize the vector matrix ?

Comment: knowing Java helps almost nothing when you want to learn C++ (or vice versa). Reading the fine manual on the other hand helps a lot: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: When `j` is `0`, what does `dp[i + 1][j - 1]` resolve to?

Comment: *but I'm trying to practice my C++* -- C++ is one of the most complex languages out there.  Given that, it is better learnt by using proper C++ books and materials, and not trying to solve random coding puzzles.  Using Java or any other language as a model in writing C++ code will result in 1) Buggy programs, 2) Inefficient programs, or 3) Programs that will look weird to an actual C++ programmer.  -- *This solution works in Java actually. In Java, I just do...* -- Doesn't matter what you did in Java, C++ is not Java.

Comment: If you don't have a C++ book handy then have a look here : https://www.learncpp.com/.
Don't forget that most material out here tries to explain datastructures (at a low level) in C++, that is not the kind of C++ you should learn. Learn about the standard library (it has  arrays, vectors, lists, maps and all kind of tested algorithms for you to reuse). Be sure to understand std::unique_ptr/std::shared_ptr too (since new/delete should be used sparingly) more on that here https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines (also don't use leetcode to learn C++!)

Comment: @OP As mentioned, change `dp[i][j] = s[i] == s[j] && (j - i < 3 || dp[i + 1][j - 1]);` to this --> `dp[i][j] = s[i] == s[j] && (j - i < 3 || dp.at(i + 1).at(j - 1));`.  Do you now get an `std::out_of_range` exception thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize a vector matrix like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<type>> vec_name{ rows, std::vector<type>(cols) };
```

..which in your case is:

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> dp{ s.length(), std::vector<bool>(s.length()) };
```

Comment: Thank you, this removed the error but there is one thing bothering me. Why does my solution pass in Java and not in C++ ? That is so odd...

Comment: @Saturnsbelt It isn't odd if you use Java as a model in writing your code.  Read my comment in the main section.  Use `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the elements, and don't be surprised if you get a `std::out_of_range` exception thrown.  You only learn about doing things like this by actually learning C++ properly, instead of doing line-by-line translations from Java to C++.

Comment: @Saturnsbelt Note that in Java you are using arrays and in C++ you are using vectors